# How to lookup DNS Record in specific zone

Tags: dns, bind, zone, nslookup, dig

For example I have a zone `example.com` and someone created a dotted hostname `app.subzone` which resolves to `app.subzone.example.com` in it.

Now I create a new zone `subzone.example.com` and an record `app`in it.

At this point I can no longer query the record `app.subzone` in the zone `example.com`, but I still can update/delete it with nsupdate, e.g.

```
nsupdate -k .key
> server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
> zone example.com
> update delete app.subzone.example.com a
> send
```

My question:

Is there any way to query for a Record in a specific zone?
I couldn't find an option for nslookup or dig.

For my concrete use case I deleted the old dotted hostname records and just wanted to check whether they are gone. At this point I found out, that nslookup does not support the same zone specifier like nsupdate.

Comment: I think your question is a better fit for the [server fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thank you @GiorgiTsiklauri, can I move it somehow?

Comment: No, you can't. You should post it there.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1032252/how-to-lookup-dns-record-in-specific-zone